# Get linear predictor from a multinom() model in R

Tags: r, multinomial, nnet

I have made a multinomial model using `multinom()` from the `nnet` package. I am trying to do internal validation and update the model but I need the linear predictor values from the model and I cannot seem to access them. I can get the predicted probabilities but cannot find a way to get the linear predictor terms.

I have tried `predict(MultiNom1, type = "link")` but it seems that you cannot use "link" as an argument for the multinomial mode. Wondering if anyone had any suggestions?

e.g.

```r
require(nnet)
require(rms)
attach(mtcars) 
car <- multinom(gear ~ am + cyl + rcs(mpg, 4)) 
predict(car, type = "link")
```

Comment: Please specify in your question where `rcs` comes from.

Comment: Sorry - it is a restricted cubic spline using from rms package

Comment: If you're just trying to extract the `terms` and `estimates` you could use `broom::tidy(car)`.